# How to randomize 3 images in a ViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, imageview

In my app I have a main viewcontroller with an imageview. Every time the user goes back to this main view, I would like 1 of 3 images to appear, but I would like to randomize them. Does anyone know the best way to get this done? Could someone point me in the right direction?

It's a universal ios app in xcode with storyboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick...

```
NSArray *imageArray = @[@"ImageName1", @"ImageName2", @"ImageName3"];
NSUInteger randomImageIndex = arc4random() % [imageArray count];
[yourImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:randomImageIndex]]];
```

**Edit:**

Add the following to your view controllers .h file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *yourImage;
```

Then within your storyboard/view link the UIImageView to yourImage.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of know-how, but what do I put in place of yourImage and setImage. Is there a way to ID the imageview?

Comment: Added some more information to my answer for you. setImage is a method on a UIImageView, you don't need to change this. You should be able to just change the imageArray and yourImage.